# Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, let $x\in X$, let $\delta <\epsilon$. Then, $\overline{B(x, \delta)} \subset B(x,\epsilon)$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, let $x\in X$, and let $\delta <\epsilon$. Then, $\overline{B(x, \delta)} \subset B(x,\epsilon)$.

My attempt:- Let $y\in \overline{B(x, \delta)}$ iff every open set containing $y$ has a non-empty intersection with $y$. Let $U_y$ be the open set containing $y$. Let $t \in U_y \cap \overline{B(x, \delta)}$, then $d(x,t)<\delta < \epsilon$. So, $y\in \overline{B(x, \epsilon)}$.  I am not getting $y\in {B(x, \epsilon)}$. Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure? Take $X = \mathbb R$, $d$ the usual absolute value, then $\varepsilon =1/2, \delta =1$ would disprove the statement. Maybe typos?

Comment: sorry it was a typo

Comment: I have corrected the error..

Comment: Pick a specific $U_y$, preferably a ball, then consider use the points in the ball and the properties of $d$ to prove $d (x,y) < \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

If $z\in \overline{B(x, \delta)}$, then for each $n\in \mathbb N$,  $B(z,1/n)\cap B(x, \delta)\neq \emptyset, $ so we may choose $y_n\in B(z,1/n)\cap B(x, \delta)$ and use the triangle inequality to write $d(z,x)\le d(z,y_n)+d(y_n,x)<1/n+\delta.$ As this is true for all integers $n$, we must have $d(z,x)\le \delta.$

To finish, choose $\delta<r<\epsilon$, and observe that $\overline{B(x, \delta)}\subset B(x,r)\subset B(x,\epsilon).$

Comment: $d(z,x)\le d(z,y_n)+d(y_n,x)<1/n+\delta.$ As this is true for all integers $n$, we must have $d(z,x)\le \delta.$ . How it is coming?

Comment: sir, I am convinced with result, If $d(z,x)\le <1/n+\delta.$ As this is true for all integers $n$, we must have $d(z,x)\le \delta.$ .

Answer (score 0):

Show that $y \in \overline{B(x,\delta)}$ implies $d(y,x) \le \delta$. So then $d(y,x) < \varepsilon$ and you've got the inclusion.

To see the implication, go for the contrapositive: $d(y,x) > \delta$ implies $y \notin \overline{B(x,\delta)}$, which follows as when $d(y,x) > \delta$, the open ball $B(y, d(y,x)-\delta)$ misses $B(x,\delta)$ by the triangle inequality (check this!) showing that $y \notin \overline{B(x,\delta)}$.

Comment: $y \in \overline{B(x,\delta)}$ implies $d(y,x) \le \delta$. Trivial implication, but problem is that definition of $\overline{A}$ is defined as the the intersection of all closed subset of X containing the set A. also one characterization is given that $y \in \overline{A)}$ iff every open set containing the point x must have the non empty intersection with A.

Comment: @Mathgeek that last one is the one I use

Comment: @Mathgeek if we already knew that the closed balls are indeed closed we’d be done by the first criterion too.

Comment: @Mathgeek if my first implication is indeed "trivial" then the inclusion you state is immediate as well.

Comment: sir, I don't understand what do you mean

Comment: I got the proof. Thank you.:)